# Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob'

Tags: azure-functions

In an Azure Function I upgraded to the latest assembly versions:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 5.0.0

> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob 11.2.3

and now I get the error (there is no WindowsAzure.Storage in the project):

> Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob'

for:

```
[Blob("thecontainer/thefile.json", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "StorageConnectionStringAzure")] ICloudBlob theBlob
```

The output of running locally is:

> Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient,
> Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'

and a load of other attempts at types, all with the message:

> but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob,
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version=11.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

Is there any way to get it to work with the latest packages?

Comment: As you have already opened an issue on GitHub, adding reference to help other community members. You can refer to [Cannot bind to ICloudBlob with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 5.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25429)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICloudBlob` was discontinued in 5.0.0. So short answer is that if you want to use 5.0.0, then update your code accordingly (replacing `ICloudBlob` with `BlobClient` iirc).

[Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#additional-types).

Comment: thank you very much. I hadn't spotted that bit that says "This version drops support for the legacy ICloudBlob".

Comment: There have been a lot of breaking changes lately with Functions, so it's hard to really keep track of it all if you ask me. I also think it's the 3rd time the packages change name; from `WindowsAzure.*` to `Microsoft.Azure.*` to `Azure.*`, and even the extension packages for isolated Functions are named differently (from the regular extension packages). *nostril exhale*

Comment: The docs say ICloudBlob is legacy and not supported but it's still in the 5.0.0 package. Not sure why something that doesn't work would still be in the package.

Comment: No surpise... Many of the new packages seems to be autogenerated/migrations where they simply move models/entities from one package to the next. In any case, the Function's execution context doesn't have the information available to bind anything to `ICloudBlob`, so that's why it fails. You could write your own extension to make it work again, but I'm 99.9% sure it's much easier to simply replace any usage of `ICloudBlob` with `BlobClient`. :)

Comment: Yes I've replaced it with BlobClient, thanks for the info